# How Does One Submit a POST Request in VB.Net With Nested POST Data

Tags: .net, vb.net, rest

I'm working with VB.NET because a client wants some example code to access our REST API.

I know that in PHP, I can easily do this by building a multi-dimentional array containing many arrays and passing the array (or stdClass) to `http_build_query()` and this works like magic:

```
$request = array (
    'param1' => 'value-1',
    'param2' => array(
        'param3' => 'value-3',
    ),
);
$query = http_build_query($request);
```

In HTML, you could create the form like:

```
<input name="param1" value="value-1">
<input name="param2[param3]" value="value-3">
```

The closest I could find to anything like this was a `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()` in VB.Net, however it only allows Key-Value pairs, you can't have a key that contains another NameValueCollection, as the Values can only be strings.

Is there an VB.Net equivalent to the PHP method, or is there a better way all together in .Net? I'm not primarily a .Net guy, and have spent quite a bit of time searching, but can't seem to find any kind of example or explanation that does anything more than simple Key-Value pairs of strings.

Comment: I think there are no equivalent in .NET for http_build_query in your case. You'll be stuck at implementing your own. Instead of putting the values in a NameValueCollection, could you just convert your initial data directly into a string?

Comment: Honestly I just need to know how to submit a multi-dimentional POST request with .Net, I don't care how I do it. I need to get one working example so I can send it off to this guy and never look at it again.

Comment: In your example, the query would be "param1=value-1&param2[param3]=value-3". Your collection could just be a list containing "param1","value-1" and "param2[param3]","value-3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an equivalent in .NET for http_build_query. You might end up having to build your own query string yourself.

In your example, the query would look like this

```
"param1=value-1&param2[param3]=value-3"
```

You could always use a NameValueCollection but the key/value field would be

```
"param1","value-1"
"param2[param3]","value-3"
```